# Add item to the cart automatically

Tags: checkout, cart, magento2.3.3, automation

Hi I'm pretty new in magento.

I need to create a blank page that, when visited by a client, automatically adds an specific item to the cart in and redirects him to the checkout screen.

How should I approach this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom page using routes.xml

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="custom" id="custom">
            <module name="Vendor_Module"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

And your controller must be in below path

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $cart;

    protected $formKey;

    protected $_productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $productSku =10;
        $product = $this->_productRepository->get($productSku);
        $params = array(
            'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
            'product' => $product->getId(), 
            'qty'   =>1
        );
        $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
        $this->cart->save();
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/index/index');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

You can access the page using `{{Your base url}}/custom/index/index`

Comment: I forgot to menction my version of magento is 2.3.3

Comment: Did you get any error ?

Comment: I think is a problem with the directory structure. App/code/vendor doesn't exist in this version.

Comment: By default it doesn't....You need to create `code` folder for creating custom extensions

Comment: And `vendor` means your company name `module` means your extension name.

Comment: Study about How to create an extension here - https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/how-create-hello-world-module-magento-2.html and apply my answer. It will work

Comment: It works indeed. Thank you so much for the hints.

Comment: Nope....Welcome